@wire getRecords issue
I'm just trying to see some Event's data in the Console window but unable to figure out where am going wrong. I'm sure its a silly mistake, please help!
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecords } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import SUBJECT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Event.Subject';

export default class TestLWC extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getRecords, { 
        recordIds: ['00UHr00001KSgP9MAL'], //brand new record created
        fields: [SUBJECT_FIELD]
    })
    loadEvents({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('data: '+data); //never reaches here
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('error: '+error); //never reaches here
        }
        console.log('data: '+data); //undefined
    }
}


The documentation is somewhat misleading if you're not paying attention. getRecords receives an array of objects that specify a record Id and the fields to retrieve. If you scroll down, you'll see this in the example. To fix this, change your code as follows:
    @wire(getRecords, { records: [
        { recordIds: ['00UHr00001KSgP9MAL'], //brand new record created
          fields: [SUBJECT_FIELD]
        }
      ]
    })

Notice how we add a records property that's an array, and in the array, we have objects that specify fields and record Ids. This allows us to retrieve multiple records of multiple data types in a single call.

Even ChatGPT doesn't know this, you're awesome!! I'm getting this error now, so I'm assuming my only option is to get the Events using Apex? data: {"results":[{"statusCode":400,"result":[{"errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE","message":"Object Event is not supported in UI API"}]}]}

@apz Yes, I hadn't thought about that, but not all object types can be retrieved through the wire service. You'll have to check out the docs for specific unsupported objects.

You are trying to wire a function to getRecords in LWC. The issue seems to be with the getRecords wire adapter usage. The getRecords method is used to retrieve multiple records.

Changed getRecords to getRecord because you are retrieving a single record.
Changed recordIds to recordId because getRecord takes a single ID, not an array.

import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'; 
import SUBJECT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Event.Subject';

export default class TestLWC extends LightningElement {
        @wire(getRecord, { 
                recordId: '00UHr00001KSgP9MAL', 
                fields: [SUBJECT_FIELD]
        })
        loadEvents({ error, data }) {
                if (data) {
                        console.log('data: ', data); 
                } else if (error) {
                        console.log('error: ', error);
                }
        }
}


Are you saying the getRecords doesn't support one recordId in a string array? Ideally, I want to get multiple records without using Apex. The code in the question was just an example.
